# PHP Form checkbox array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have the following HTML form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="markpaid[]">
<input name="paymentdate[]" value="$paymenttodaydate" type="text">
```

When submitting this form to PHP, I do:

```
$markpaid = $this->input->post('markpaid[]');
$paymentdate = $this->input->post('paymentdate[]');

for ($i=0;$i<count($markpaid);$i++) {
   echo $paymentdate[$i];
}
```

The result always include the first array. I want to grab only $paymentdate value where the corresponding checkbox is checked.

Any tip?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the issue is, but if there's a correlation between the two fields you should link them with a ID, perhaps like so `name="markpaid[<ID>][]" / name="paymentdate[<ID>][]"`

Comment: your checkbox doesn't have value part and this html snippet will run inside some loop or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="markpaid[] value="$due->poreceivedid">
<input name="paymentdate-$due->poreceivedid" value="$paymenttodaydate" type="text">
```

PHP

```
$markpaid = $this->input->post('markpaid[]');
for ($i=0;$i<count($markpaid);$i++) {
   $paymentdate = $this->input->post('paymentdate-'.$markpaid[$i].'');
}
```

Thanks @Epodax, @abhishek-gurjar, @akshayp for the hint

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['markpaid'] as $value) {
echo ($value);
}
```

try markpaid[] in POST too if ::

Answer (score -1):

Remove `[]` from below :

```
 $markpaid = $this->input->post('markpaid[]');
 $paymentdate = $this->input->post('paymentdate[]');
```

This will be :

```
 $markpaid = $this->input->post('markpaid');
 $paymentdate = $this->input->post('paymentdate');
```

Now `$markpaid` and `$paymentdate` will give you arrays with selected check box values.

**[Reference](https://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/)**